# Tensorflow continuous fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm using the latest version of tensorflow and I was wondering how I can fit the my model multiple times without resetting the previous learned weights.

e.g

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=256, input_dim=8640, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

samples = [1,.7.. 1,.3]
labels = [1,0.. 2,1]

model.fit(x=samples, y=labels, batch_size=64, epochs=100, verbose=2, validation_split=.15)

samples = [.5,.3.. 0,.7]
labels = [2,1.. 1,0]

model.fit(x=samples, y=labels, batch_size=64, epochs=100, verbose=2, validation_split=.15)
```

I'm doing this because the entire dataset is too large to store in memory(> 8 GB RAM)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to start looking for Generators.